# Need help loading a 20gb json.gz file into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a json.gz file which is around 20gb. I loaded that file into google cloud storage but unable to load it into big query as there is limit of 4GB compressed file I can load directly from google cloud storage. What are my options here, how can I load that data into BQ?

Is there a way to split the .gz file into smaller chunks without line breaks and load into BQ?

Comment: How did you get 20GB file in cloud storage?

Comment: uploaded from FTP

Comment: You will want to break your file into smaller chunks and load those or load uncompressed data (more expensive as it uses more storage).  Does your json have any top-level dates/timestamps that you can split by?

Comment: No date fields to split by

Comment: Can you try extracting your .gz file then loading the data? As per [BQ Load limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#:~:text=The%20size%20limit%20for%20an%20uncompressed%20JSON%20file%20is%205%20TB.) you should be able to load up to 5 TB of uncompressed data.